# Can't open Python 3.x graphs from double click

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter

So, I am trying to create a GUI with buttons that will run other python scripts which generate graphs. All my .py files will are set to open by default with the python.exe.

```py
import os
import tkinter


top=tkinter.Tk()

def helloCallBack():
    os.system('C:\StarGrams\Tkinter_Play\TestGraph.py')

B=tkinter.Button(top,text="hello",command= helloCallBack)
B.pack()
top.mainloop()
```

When I run this code and press the button, it seems to open the file and run the script, but nothing pops up.
now if I have it open another Tkinter code, the window will successfully pop up, it seems to just not work with the graph

Comment: first: I would use \\ instead of \ in path because \ has special meaning in text - ie. `\n`, `\t`. OR use / instead of \ . Second: to make sure I would rather run `full/path/to/python.exe C:\StarGrams\Tkinter_Play\TestGraph.py`. Third: what do you have in `TestGraph.py` ? Maybe there is something missing in code.

Comment: Maybe you have relative imports or files that don't exist that are breaking? `os.system` doesn't let you see the output, I would recommend using [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html) instead. Try running the script from another directory, e.g. in `StarGrams`, `python3 Tkinter_Play\TestGraph.py` and see if that works.